# Online course hosting

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web-services

I have a business providing class training and workshops for businesses, and want to develop an online version to link to my website and sell to businesses as an online version for them to use for their staff, and charge them a monthly fee for access. This obviously requires not just a hosting site, but the ability to manage client access so they can access it multiple times for their staff. In short it needs to be:

- online access through my current websitw (at least to access the hosting website for the course)
- intergrated payment methods for subscription, or ability to link to my own methods
- clients to have access to their own login/area multiple times for their staff to use, but also allowing me to control their access and material etc.

Its not an area I know anything about, and would really appreciate the help!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking to something similar to [this](https://drupalize.me/) site, which has all the requirements you mentioned included (disclosure: I'm not affiliated with it in any way). If you agree, and (probably) wonder something like "*How did they do that?*", then this is the answer: [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/). And BTW, Drupal is free and opensource ...

PS: I can probably come up with a dozen of similar sites (I just picked the one that first came to my mind).

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. It would be a good solution for a ground up process, but do you have an recommendations of platforms I could intergrate with my current website etc?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas by Instructure is an excellent LMS, there is  an AGPL licensed version you can download and run yourself.  Rich well documented RESTful API, can do all sorts of integrations.  Some simple middleware to control enrollments,etc.

I don't work for Instructure, but I am the Canvas admin at the college I work at and I do some LTI and API development for it to extend some functionality for our students and staff.